# How can I convert from LONGLONG to class _variant_t?

Tags: c++, windows-ce, variant, long-long

In this example m_Amount is CString. stringToNumber function converts it to a LONGLONG number successfully. But when I want to assign it to a variant I get this error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from '__int64' to 'class _variant_t'
```

mycode

```
_variant_t  myVar = _variant_t( (LONGLONG)stringToNumber(m_Amount) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using _variant_t to insert LONGLONG data into the SQL server database. As mentioned in [this asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409134/779408) numeric is mapped to CString in C++. So I retrieve my numeric data from database as string, convert it to LONGLONG, change and then convert it to string again and store result string to database.

**SQL numeric --(retrieve from database)--> string -> LONGLONG -> string --(insert into the database)--> SQL numeric**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the cast.

Use:

```
_variant_t(
   __int64 i8Src
)
```

See [`_variant_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k74e1xsh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) MSDN for further reference.

Windows CE however does not provide all data types available on a regular Windows XP/Vista/Win 7 installation. In your case, this means that WinCE does not support 64-bit signed/unsigned integers. So, you are best advised to use either a narrower data type or roll your own type (that uses perhaps two `int`s) to get a `LONGLONG`.

Comment: is this code correct? `_variant_t  myVar = _variant_t( stringToNumber(m_Amount) );`

Comment: Yes! This should work. Also, I prefer the following: `_variant_t myVar( stringToNumber(m_Amount) );`.

Comment: BTW: Aren't you better off using `VARIANT` or `CComVariant` (until unless you have project specific requirements)?

Comment: `_variant_t myVar = _variant_t( stringToNumber(m_Amount) );` did not work and get same error. i can not change the type of myVar unfortunately.

Comment: Are you on using Windows CE? In that case you may have to use a narrower integer type.

Comment: I am developing on Windows Mobile by eVC++.

Answer (score 0):

What toolchain are you using?

There should be a conversion from `__int64` to `_variant_t` if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x501`, which corresponds to a target of at least WinXP.  That should be true for up to date Windows toolchains, but you may need to explicitly set that macros definition yourself with some older tools (like VS 2005, I believe).

Comment: I am developing on Windows Mobile by eVC++. I did not get your purpose. I am new in C++

Comment: Ah - I'm not familiar with eVC++ and whatever SDK it might be using, but I wouldn't be too surprised if it doesn't support `__int64` in the `_variant_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
union UltimateCast
{
   __int64 From;
   __variant_t To;
};
```

Put the __int64 value you need to cast from into the From field. After that read the resulting value from the To field.

Comment: Save your int64 value into From field and read the casting result from To. This is actually a reinterpret cast.

Comment: how these values are converted?

Comment: I have fixed the answer according to the comment above. The values share the same memory location, so one will be interpreted as the other.

Comment: what is this error: `error C2621: union 'UltimateCast' : member 'To' has copy constructor`

Comment: @breceivemail: Union's in C++03 were not allowed to have types with copy ctors (or assignment operators or non-trivial ctors). Some compiler may provide this as a feature but WinCE probably doesn't.

Comment: @TonyPerez: This won't work on his system. He is using WinCE and the compiler complies with C++03 where union members cannot have non-trivial special member functions: `object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects`.