# What is the corresponding C++ data type to the SQL numeric(18,0) data type?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

What is the corresponding C++ data type to the SQL numeric(18,0) data type?

I need a data type in C++ to store numeric(18,0) of SQL in it.

Comment: (18,0) means 18 digits before the decimal point and 0 after. So you can use a `long long` or `int64_t` or `__int64` or whatever is the 64 bit integer on your system.

Comment: my problem is _variant_t that reads data from sql does not support LONGLONG

Comment: You are using MSVC, right? What version? AFAIK variant_t does support 64 bits ints. Oh, and what kind of database are you reading from? SQL Server?

Comment: Oh, I just read your other question, where you say this is for the WinCE platform, and _variant_t doesn't contain __int64 there. I didn't know, and I have no idea how to solve that, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says on MSDN that the numeric is mapped to CString in C++.

Reference: *[SQL: SQL and C++ Data Types (ODBC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/odbc/sql-sql-and-cpp-data-types-odbc)*

Answer (score 1):

That would be a `long long` (at least 64 bits).